# jsxgraph.js: Best way to kill all event listeners

Tags: jsxgraph

When we jump from one jsxgraph sketch to another, some processes continuous to work in the background. I would like to know what is the best way of kill all event listeners in jsxgraph.js. For example, in the case of "update hooks" we can use the JXG.Board method removeHook(). But this method is deprecated in favor of JXG.Board.off(). On the other hand, the methods JXG.Board.off() and JXG.Board.on() do not have any documentation.

Anyway, my question is how can I kill all running eventHandlers and processes associated with a given board, before a jump to the next sketch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for JXG.Board.on() and JXG.Board.off() is at https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/JXG.EventEmitter.html.

The recommended way to get rid of all event listeners is to call    `JXG.JSXGraph.freeBoard(board)` and init a new board.

In order to only remove all event listeners on JSXGraph elements and on the board itself - without removing the board - a cumbersome way (like in general  JavaScript code) is to call `off` in the same way as the `on` method for all event listeners.

A very hacker-like method would be to set

```
JXG.EventEmitter.eventHandlers = {};
```

This should remove all event listeners on JSXGraph elements on the whole HTML page.

Comment: Oh yes, I think freeBoard() would be sufficient in my case. I like very much your library!